# Why do we need a Route Distinguisher in VPNv4 routes if there is already a VPN label?

Tags: mpls, vrf, l3vpn

I know the explanation about the usage of RD, that it makes routes from different VRFs globally unique.
AFAIK, a VPN route is composed of `[RD] + [VPN label] + [Prefix]`
Isn't the VPN label, that is allocated for each VRF anyway, enough to make the route globally unique?
Isn't `[VPN label] + [prefix]` unique enough?

Is RD used because it's user configurable and allows for more control? unlike VPN labels that are randomly allocated by the router.

Or maybe RD is used - since a VPN label isn't always mapped directly to a VRF (maybe sometimes it's mapped to a route directly, to save a VRF IP lookup when forwarding traffic towards a CE router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AFAIK, a VPN route is composed of [RD] + [VPN label] + [Prefix]

That's not correct.  A route is RD + prefix.

Remember packets have labels -- routes have distinguishers

An MPLS VPN is a bit abstract.  It's a collection of VRFs that share a common route policy.

Comment: so is it possible that two or more VRFs are represented by a single a label? (Should they have the same RD in that case?)

Comment: You are confusing two separate things.  Labels do not define VPNs

Comment: So what do VPN labels define then?

Comment: They define the flow from the ingress LSR to the egress LSR.

Comment: There are two labels, I'm talking about the inner label that represents the VRF

Comment: So am I.  Again, I think you're confusing routes with packets.

Comment: Mmm... packets have labels, true. But control plane is also aware of these labels. The difference is that RD is not part of the actual packet, whereas VPN label is. According to VPN label signaling via BGP, packet knows to arrive to the correct VRF.